# Why does this use Double instead of giving me an ambiguity error?

Tags: haskell

For the code

```
class Boomable a where
  boom :: a

instance Boomable Int where
  boom = 100

instance Boomable Double where
  boom = 1.2
```

Why does

```
boom + 1
```

give me `2.2`?

Why does it use the `Double` version instead of giving me an ambiguity error as I expected?

I expected having to do `::Int` or `::Double` on either `boom` or `1` for this to work.

Comment: How did you test it? In GHCi?

Comment: ghci does type defaulting. There may be some flag to disable that, I don't actually know though.

Comment: Ok, that explains it then? You're right, if I do `foo = boom + 1` in GHCi it uses the `Double`, but if I do the same thing in my `.hs` file it gives me an ambiguity error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can enable the warnings using `ghci -Wall`:

```
$ ghci -Wall

Prelude> :set +m
Prelude> class Boomable a where
Prelude|   boom :: a
Prelude| 
Prelude> instance Boomable Int where
Prelude|   boom = 100
Prelude| 
Prelude> instance Boomable Double where
Prelude|   boom = 1.2
Prelude| 
Prelude> boom + 1

<interactive>:12:6: Warning:
    Defaulting the following constraint(s) to type `Double'
      (Num a0) arising from a use of `+' at <interactive>:12:6
      (Boomable a0) arising from a use of `boom' at <interactive>:12:1-4
    In the expression: boom + 1
    In an equation for `it': it = boom + 1

<interactive>:12:6: Warning:
    Defaulting the following constraint(s) to type `Double'
      (Num a0) arising from a use of `+' at <interactive>:12:6
      (Show a0) arising from a use of `print' at <interactive>:12:1-8
      (Boomable a0) arising from a use of `boom' at <interactive>:12:1-4
    In the expression: boom + 1
    In an equation for `it': it = boom + 1
2.2
```